# $x^2-y^2=196$, can we find the value of $x^2+y^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

$x$ and $y$ are positive integers.

If $x^2-y^2=196$, can we know what the value of $x^2+y^2$ is?

Can anyone explain this to me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rewrite the equation to get $x^2=y^2+196$. Now write $x=y+k$, then $$x^2=(y+k)^2=y^2+2yk+k^2=y^2+196$$

Therefore $2yk+k^2=196$

Now note that $k \mid 196$ and $k$ must be even.

This leaves the possibilities $2,4,14,28,98,196$.

$k=2$ gives $y=48$.

$k=4$ gives $y=22.5$, which is not an integer.

$k=14$ gives $y=0$, but that is not positive.

Similiar, for larger $k$, it won't be positive.

So $y=48$, therefore $$x^2+y^2=(x^2-y^2)+2y^2=196+2\cdot48^2=4804$$

Answer (score 11):

$$
x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)=14^2
$$
Since $(x+y)-(x-y)=2y$ either both $x+y$ and $x-y$ need to be even or both need to be odd. Since their product is even, both need to be even. There are two possible factorizations: $14\cdot14$ and $2\cdot98$. $14\cdot14$ implies $y=0$, so we want $x-y=2$ and $x+y=98$. That is, $x=50$ and $y=48$. Therefore,
$$
x^2+y^2=4804
$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint 1:** $x^2-y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$.

**Hint 2:** Divisors of $196$: $1$, $2$, $4$, $7$, $14$, $28$, $49$, $98$, $196$.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to find out $x^2+y^2$, as $196$, which will be $(x-y)(x+y)$, can be factorised as five possible integer products, $14\times 14$, $7\times28$, $4\times 49$, $2\times 98$, $1\times 196$.

Of these only one product leads to both positive and integer solutions for $x$ and $y$. Can you work out which of the products this will be?

Answer (score 1):

Just use Pythagora's theorem:$$x^2=y^2+(14)^2$$

$$y=p^2-q^2$$
$$z=2pq=14$$
$$x=p^2+q^2$$
Since $2pq=14$ and $p,q$ are coprime, we can only have $(p,q)=(\pm1,\pm7);(\pm7,\pm 1)$
From here, it is easy:
$$x^2+y^2=50^2+48^2= 4804
$$

Comment: How could $x^2+y^2$ be smaller than $x^2-y^2$?

Comment: Thanks I am made the correction.

Comment: Edit: I meant $z=14$ and $y=p^2-q^2$.

Comment: Before claiming $p,q$ are coprime you must prove that $x,z,14$ can't have a common divisor. But you could've entirely omitted stating they're coprime in your proof and it would still be correct.

Comment: You also assumed wlog that $p,q\ge 0$, but you didn't state this assumption.